# ViewPager листает все страницы

Tags: android

ViewPager листает все страницы

Я сейчас говорю про кнопочные действия. Тобишь я нахожусь на 6 странице, жму кнопку я перемещаюсь на 1 страницу через функцию viewpager.current.

Можно ли сделать так чтобы пролистывание было не по всем, а сразу с 6 на 1.

А то получается что будто листаются все страницы

Comment: можно анимацию перелистывания убрать  setCurrentItem(index, false);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Второй аргумент метода `setCurrentItem(int item, boolean smoothScroll)` как раз отвечает за прокрутку, если присвоить ему значение `false`, то будет мгновенный переход.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы имеете в виду "бесконечное" перелистывание, то наиболее простой, но несколько костыльный вариант это в адаптере ViewPager'а возвращать в getCount какое-нибудь очень большое число, например 10000, при создании вьюхи для конкретной позиции считать реальную позицию как остаток от деления на реальное количество страниц, ну и при инициализации педжера выставлять по умолчанию позицую где то в середине, то есть 5000. Так можно будет почти бесконечно листать красиво переходя с последней страницы на первую или наоборот.